# Changing columns to rows using gridview and ITextsharp in mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, gridview, itext

I am presently trying to switch from columns and use rows when displaying my headings on pdf as I am creating a leave application form.

I want to get my column headings to reflect as rows. E.g. Name:Rivash ...next line surname: Ben ...and so on. At present data is displayed in a column format when exported to pdf.

Here is the code in the Controller.

```
public FileStreamResult ExporttoPdfLeave()
{
    List<EmployeeLeaveViewModel> viewModelList = new List<EmployeeLeaveViewModel>();
    var model = _employeeleaveRepository.GetAllEmployeeLeave().ToList();

    foreach (var items in model)
    {
        EmployeeLeaveViewModel objEmployeeLeaveViewModel = new EmployeeLeaveViewModel();
        objEmployeeLeaveViewModel.emp_first_name = items.Employee_Details.emp_first_name;
        objEmployeeLeaveViewModel.emp_surname = items.Employee_Details.emp_surname;

        objEmployeeLeaveViewModel.emp_tel_no = items.Employee_Details.emp_tel_no;
        objEmployeeLeaveViewModel.persal_no = items.persal_no;
        objEmployeeLeaveViewModel.no_of_days = items.no_of_days;
        objEmployeeLeaveViewModel.c_start_date = items.c_start_date;
        objEmployeeLeaveViewModel.end_date = items.end_date;
        viewModelList.Add(objEmployeeLeaveViewModel);
    }

    WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(source: viewModelList, canPage: false, canSort: false);
    string gridHTML = grid.GetHtml(


       columns: grid.Columns
        (
        grid.Column("persal_no", "Persal number"),
         grid.Column("emp_first_name", "Name"),
         grid.Column("emp_surname", "Surname"),
         grid.Column("duly_completed"," Duly completed"),
         grid.Column("correct_leave_form", "Correct leave form"),
         grid.Column("correct_leave_type", "Correct leave type"),
         grid.Column("eight_week_cycle", "Eight week cycle"),
         grid.Column("med_cert", " Medical certificate"),
         grid.Column("med_cert_completed", " Medical certificate completed"),
         grid.Column("pattern", "Pattern"),
         grid.Column("counselling", "Counselling"),
         grid.Column("no_of_days", "No of days"),
          grid.Column("c_start_date", "Start date"),
          grid.Column("end_date", "End date"),
          grid.Column("emp_tel_no", "Contact number")
        )).ToString();

    string exportData = String.Format("<html><head>{0}</head><body>{1}</body></html>",
        "<style>table{ border-spacing: 10px;  border-collapse: collapse; border: solid; }" +
        " td{border-color: #191970; border-width: 1px 1px 0 0; border-style: solid; margin: 0; padding: 4px; background-color: #E0FFFF;}</style>", gridHTML);

    var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(exportData);

    using (var input = new MemoryStream(bytes))
    {
        var output = new MemoryStream();

        var document = new iTextSharp.text.Document(PageSize.A4,50,50,50,50);

        var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, output);

        writer.CloseStream = false;

        document.Open();

        var xmlWorker = iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance();

        xmlWorker.ParseXHtml(writer, document, input, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);

        document.Close();

        output.Position = 0;

        return new FileStreamResult(output, "application/pdf");
    }
}
```

Comment: And your problem is...?

Comment: I want to get my column headings to reflect as rows. Eg Name:Rivash ...next line surname: Ben ...and so on. At present data is displayed in a column format when exported to pdf.

Comment: There's three main parts to this problem, the `GridView`, the HTML and iTextSharp? Do you want to change your `GridView` in some way or do you want that to stay the same? Next, the HTML that's generated, does it look how you want it to or do you need to change that? Last, does the PDF look like your HTML? Nor your `GridView` mind you, your _html_ is **the only thing that iTextSharp sees**

Comment: At present I just need the headings in the columns to display in the rows like you would have on an application form that's what I want to change in the GridView. The pdf does look like the html generated. I used this technique to create reports(which columns are ideal for) prior to trying to create and application form. However I just need the column headings in rows and unsure how to do that.

Comment: Ended up using this javascript and it works great http://forums.asp.net/t/1261525.aspx